# How to install Ansible in Amazon Linux EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I pick this Amazon Linux: Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-1a033c7a.
I installed Ansible using the command:

```
sudo pip install ansible,
```

it shows install completes.when I run ansible --version, it shows:

```
ansible 2.4.1.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ec2-    
user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov  2 2017, 19:20:38) [GCC 4.8.5     
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

Why `config file = None`? Shouldn't it shows `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`? I do not see `/etc/ansible/hosts`, not even folder `/etc/ansible`. Did I install correctly, where is the folder `/etc/ansible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I answer the question myself.

There are many ways to install ansible, and then you get difference default settings, depending on the OS. Many tutorials just assume the ansible_hosts and ansible.cfg already in /etc/ansible, which is not correct if you install ansible using pip.

In fact, if you install ansible using pip, then you will not see ansible.cfg and ansible_hosts in /etc/ansible. Even the folder /etc/ansible does not exist. but never mind, you can create these two files yourself as follows:

suppose you want to store ansible_hosts and ansible.cfg in /home/ec2-user, then you can:

```
echo <remote_host> /home/ec2-user/ansible_hosts
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=/home/ec2-user/ansible_hosts
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg
mv ansible.cfg /home/ec2-user/
export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/ec2-user/ansible.cfg
```

then if ansible --version, you will see

```
ansible 2.4.1.0
  config file = /home/ec2-user/ansible.cfg
....
```

and if you test ansible ad-hoc command (my remote_host is ubuntu, so I use -u ubuntu, you can change it to be yours):

```
ansible all -m ping -u ubuntu
```

then you see ansible ping remote_host successfully.

This shows ansible does work.

Answer (score 6):

> why `config file = None`?

Because at the time of running `ansible --version` no config file was found.

> shouldn't it shows `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`?

No. It should show the `ansible.cfg` actually being used.

Per documentation, Ansible tries to find the config file in:

> - `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (an environment variable)
> - `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
> - `.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
> - `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

`ansible --version` will show you the exact path to the one being used.

<sup>Strictly speaking the last point is not always true, as package managers and virtual environment managers might cause the `/etc` directory to be located elsewhere.</sup>

> did I install correctly

You didn't mention any error or warning during the installation and `ansible --version` returned a proper response.

There is no reason not to believe it's installed properly.

> where is the folder `/etc/ansible`?

It's not existing on your system. There is no default inventory file, nor configuration file created by the installation package.

Create one.

Comment: Thanks techraf. it is so weird that many tutorial said I will see hosts and config file in /etc/ansible, but in fact if install using pip these two files and even /etc/ansible do not exist and I have to create them myself. looks like my ansible can at least ping.